# What is the benefit of '#pragma omp master' as opposed to '#pragma omp single'?

Tags: openmp

In OpenMP any code inside a `#pragma omp master` directive is executed by a single thread (the master), without an implied barrier at end of the region. (See [section on MASTER directive in the LLNL OpenMP tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#MASTER)).

This seems equivalent to `#pragma omp single nowait` (with the exception that rather than the 'master', any thread may execute the single region).

Under what circumstances, if any, is it beneficial to use `#pragma omp master`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Though a `single nowait` construct is most of the time equivalent to a `master` construct:

1. The `master` construct can be used inside a work-sharing construct, should any need arise. This is not the case for a `single nowait` construct, as two work-sharing constructs can't be nested within the same parallel region
2. Some libraries want the main thread to perform certain operations. For instance the MPI library, when initialized with a level of thread support equal to  [`MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Init_thread.html), allows only the main threads to make MPI calls

Comment: I'm not aware of any implementation for which MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED performs better than MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED, although I understand how the difference can emerge.

Comment: The `master` construct cannot be used inside a work-sharing construct. As the standard says: "A master region may not be closely nested inside a worksharing, atomic, or explicit task region." I'm also not sure what the semantics should be of a master nested in a parallel for loop, for example.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to nesting limitations `single` construct can be implemented slower than `master` construct because it is more complicated and flexible.  You may want to check your particular implementation, but in general `master` can be implemented faster, so multiple invocations of it may benefit comparing to `single nowait` construct.