# Does the main thread surely enters an OpenMP parallel section?

Tags: openmp

I need to check continuously through a callback provided by a closed source module a terminating condition. The thread then enters a parallel section. I don't know if this callback is safe to call from other threads other the one that received it, so if I want to use it from within the parallel section, I should have only the main, "originating" thread call it. I can do that, but I need the assumption that the main thread always enters it, or the callback won't be called. Does that hold?

Comment: I believe you can write your code to do as you wish.  I haven't a clue whether or not you have written your code to do as you wish.  How could I without sight of your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [OpenMP 4.5 Complete Specifications](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf)

> When any thread encounters a parallel construct, the thread creates a
>   team of itself and zero or more additional threads and becomes the
>   master of the new team.

So yes the main thread enters the oMP *section*.

Note that the term *section* may not be appropriate here, as if you have several `#pragma omp section`, you won't know which thread will execute which one.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe fits

```
#pragma omp master
```

See [What is the benefit of '#pragma omp master' as opposed to '#pragma omp single'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820471/what-is-the-benefit-of-pragma-omp-master-as-opposed-to-pragma-omp-single) for more details